# What software is it produced with?

Tags: flash, simulation, software-design

I want to design a program [like this](http://www.luizmonteiro.com/Learning_VOR_Sim_2.aspx) but I don't know to start where and what software is it produced with?

If you have any idea I will appreciate you.
I want to use it in pc not in browser.

It is a flight instrument simulator.
I want to creat an interactive simulator like attached link, however it is for browser and I want to creat exe form.
Consider there are some gauges that are interrelated and respond to changes made by the user.
For example there is a screen that shows a small car when the user change its position the gauge indicate its relative changes in position and so on
below is a video of my desired simulator, I want something like this:
[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1foiLtzFxity1y0aNxRntpLFukXHmpIYg/view?usp=sharing)
note that when I'm changing airplane position, the gauge reactions simultaneously.

Comment: Your link takes us to a website not a program. There is a lot of things going on in that website so **it's not obvious** what _"a program like this"_ actually means... **(1)** Describe the program you want to create (what does it try to do) **(2)** On PC you can use Microsoft C# (try SharpDevelop as IDE) or you can use Adobe AIR to produce EXE files. Since you're a beginner try Adobe AIR (you'll also need an IDE like FlashDevelop or Adobe Animate, etc).

Comment: I assume by "*program*" you mean that satellite-view flight simulator. Although "please recommend" questions is out-of-scope here, a piece of advice: start with googling "*game  engine free sdk*". Game engine is a software dedicated to game development, i.e. game engines provide a lots of things (mostly graphics- and environment- related) you would need anyway. There are plenty of game engines so take your time reading. Narrow them by the ability to publish for PC and your other requirements. Compare them all. Pick one. Do you thing from there on.

Comment: -@VC.One. I added video and more descriptions

Comment: @AliValizadegan So did you download Adobe Air and an IDE like Adobe Animate or FlashDevelop?